# Scrapy DEBUG: Filtered offsite request

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I wants to scrape googlepatent.com everything working and almost a week ago I am getting error, I don't know where is the error here is my code.

```
allowed_domains = ['www.google.com','google.com',]
start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/search?q=mobiles&tbm=pts&sxsrf=AJOqlzXrlIIii_GtGMCheGMJHKPpQl1hLw%3A1673692348905&source=hp&ei=vITCY_2YNOKVxc8P79uA2A8&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAY8KSzHAkD8f8N_ul8boy27FJhuidI9c7&ved=0ahUKEwj95qrv7cb8AhXiSvEDHe8tAPsQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=mobiles&gs_lcp=Cg9nd3Mtd2l6LXBhdGVudHMQAzIECCMQJzIFCAAQkQIyBAgAEEMyCggAEIAEEIcCEBQyCAgAEIAEELEDMggIABCABBCxAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyCAgAEIAEELEDMggIABCABBCxAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQyQM6CAgAELEDEIMBOgUIABCABDoFCAAQsQM6BQgAEJIDUABYygxg1g1oAHAAeACAAfADiAG4DpIBAzQtNJgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-patents']
```

This is parse and other_link function

```
def parse(self, response):

        title = response.xpath("//div[@class='yuRUbf']/a/h3/text()").extract_first()
        realetd_data = response.xpath("//div[@class='yuRUbf']/a/@href").get()

       

        yield response.follow(url = realetd_data, callback = self.other_link)


    def other_link(self,response):
        heading = response.xpath("//div[@class='abstract style-scope patent-text']/text()").get()

        yield{
            'heading': heading
        }
```

I am getting this

```
> DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.google.com/search?q=mobiles&tbm=pts&sxsrf=AJOqlzXrlIIii_GtGMCheGMJHKPpQl1hLw%3A1673692348905&source=hp&ei=vITCY_2YNOKVxc8P79uA2A8&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAY8KSzHAkD8f8N_ul8boy27FJhuidI9c7&ved=0ahUKEwj95qrv7cb8AhXiSvEDHe8tAPsQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=mobiles&gs_lcp=Cg9nd3Mtd2l6LXBhdGVudHMQAzIECCMQJzIFCAAQkQIyBAgAEEMyCggAEIAEEIcCEBQyCAgAEIAEELEDMggIABCABBCxAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyCAgAEIAEELEDMggIABCABBCxAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQyQM6CAgAELEDEIMBOgUIABCABDoFCAAQsQM6BQgAEJIDUABYygxg1g1oAHAAeACAAfADiAG4DpIBAzQtNJgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-patents>
> (referer: None) 2023-01-14 16:43:26 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite]
> DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.google.com.pk': <GET
> https://www.google.com.pk/patents/WO2006010333A1?cl=en&dq=mobiles&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCmP_c_cb8AhW-qZUCHW4ZABYQ6AF6BAgFEAM>
> 2023-01-14 16:43:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider
> (finished) 2023-01-14 16:43:26 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping
> Scrapy stats:
```

Can You Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allowed_domains = ['www.google.com','google.com', ' https://www.google.com.pk']
```

This should work, you need to update `allowed_domains`

Comment: Thank You so muh replying. I tried but same results

Comment: [allowed_domains](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=allowed_domains%20#scrapy.Spider.allowed_domains) shouldn't include the `http/s` and `www` parts. In your case only `google.com` is correct.